# How do I perform atomic updates of fields of a MongoDB document?

Tags: java, mongodb, atomic, database

Disclaimer: I'm a noob to Mongo and to databases in general, so if I'm off on terminology or concepts please let me know.

For the purposes of this example, I'd like to store the mouse coordinates together within an object nested within a document. That document would look something like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f39805d35919a2a7c7aba3e"), "mouseLoc" : { "x" : 10, "y" : 20 } }
```

It seems like [atomic updating, via modifier operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-ModifierOperations), is the way to go, as I'm only storing values here (retrieving them elsewhere, in other software).  However, I can't figure out the query part.  How do I access this document in order to set the x and y values?

I'm using Java, so I'm currently trying:

```
BasicDBObject mouseLoc = new BasicDBObject();
mouseLoc.put("x", mouseX);
mouseLoc.put("y", mouseY);
myCollection.update(queryObj, new BasicDBObject("$set", mouseLoc), true, false);
```

However, I don't know how to specify that queryObj to get the document with the mouseLoc key.  Alternatively, if there's a smarter way to store information like this, please school me.

I can follow along with Mongo shell/JS tips if that's simpler.

**UPDATE:**
I can query for this document if I give it a static field like 'name'.  So, to update this document:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f39805d35919a2a7c7aba3e"), "name" : "mouseLoc", "mouseLoc" : { "x" : 10, "y" : 20 } }
```

I can use this code:

```
BasicDBObject mouseLoc = new BasicDBObject();
mouseLoc.put("x", mouseX);
mouseLoc.put("y", mouseY);

BasicDBObject queryObj = new BasicDBObject("name", "mouseLoc");
BasicDBObject updateObj = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("mouseLoc", mouseLoc));

myCollection.update(queryObj, updateObj, true, false);
```

However, it seems redundant to have to specify that "name" field just to be able to retrieve the document with the "mouseLoc" key.  Maybe I'm just misunderstanding database / mongo design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query part is where you specify a way to find you document, e.g: the `_id` or another unique field.

In your example, it will look like this:

```
ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId("4f39805d35919a2a7c7aba3e");
BasicDBObject queryObj = new BasicDBObject("_id", objectId);
```

(Maybe there's something missing about `ObjectId`, since I don't know Java.)

**UPDATE**

If you are searching for a specific `mouseLoc`, the `queryObj` will be the very `mouseLoc` object. (In JSON it would be `{ 'x': mouseX, 'y': mouseY }`.)

Comment: ObjectId is actually just copied straight from a shell find(), it's not a Java thing.  Right, that's how I'm using the query param.  However, I'd like to just retrieve the document with some "mouseLoc" key, regardless of its value.  Am I misunderstanding database design?  Do I have to have a unique name-value pair, like your "_id" example, or my update above that uses a "name" field?

Comment: @ericsoco To retrieve some document from its `mouseLoc`, make it be the `queryObj`. However, if you are updating to new X and Y, you'll have two `mouseLoc`s: `mouseLocBefore` (the `queryObj`) and `mouseLocAfter` (the updating object), and you can use both in the same update command: `myCollection.update(mouseLocBefore, mouseLocAfter, true, false);`.

Comment: I don't want to retrieve a document using its `mouseLoc`; I am updating to a new X and Y. I won't necessarily know the previous X and Y, e.g. when I restart the application writing the mouse coords.  In short, I don't want to store the previous state just in order to write the new state.  Sounds like I need **some** known state (key+value) in order to retrieve a document.  Correct?

Comment: You need some field to identify your document. I suppose you have many documents in your collection, each one with a different mouseLoc. How do you distinguish the use of each mouseLoc? Eg.: this is the mouseLoc over the image; that is the mouseLoc when clicked the button, etc. Or: this is the mouseLoc at time T, that is the mouseLoc at time W. This field, where you identify your mouseLoc meaning, is the query field. If you have only one document in your collection, you can use an empty object. If you have only one document with `mouseLoc` in your collection, the queryObj will use `$exists`.

Comment: `$exists` is what I was looking for.  Looking at the docs for `$exists` (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists), I see it's inefficient. This makes sense, and I understand now that my document should have a field with a unique value that identifies the document and perhaps hints at its use.  Thanks for your persistence getting me to understand this ;)

Comment: @ericsoco I was reading... `$exists` is not inefficient in your case (only one document with `mouseLoc`). The doc says: "... since it will effectively have to scan all indexed values", but in this particular case there will be only one document to be indexed on `mouseLoc`. Anyway, feel free to model your database as you consider better to suit your needs. MongoDB give us enough freedom! :)

Answer (score 0):

what about using the `.` specifier?

```
myCollection.updateOne(Document.parse("{ \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"4f39805d35919a2a7c7aba3e\")}"),
    Document.parse("{$set:{ \"mouseLoc.x\" : "+mouseX+", \"mouseLoc.y\" : "+mouseY+" }")
)
```